# How to create an extension method for ToString?

Tags: c#, .net, tostring

I have tried this:

```
public static class ListHelper
{
    public static string ToString<T>(this IList<String> list)
    {
        return string.Join(", ", list.ToArray());
    }

    public static string ToString<T>(this String[] array)
    {
        return string.Join(", ", array);
    }
}
```

But it does not work, both for `string[]` and `List<string>`. Maybe I need some special annotations?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Extension methods are only checked if there are *no applicable candidate methods* that match.  In the case of a call to `ToString()` there will *always* be an applicable candidate method, namely, the `ToString()` on `object`.  The purpose of extension methods is to *extend* the set of methods available on a type, not to *override* existing methods; that's why they're called "extension methods". If you want to override an existing method then you'll have to make an overriding method.

Comment: +1. A reference to MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx (see examples section)

Answer (score 6):

Simply you **Shouldn't use** the name **`ToString`** for the Extension method as it will never be called because that method already exist and **you shouldn't use `T`** as its useless there.

For example i tried this and again it returned same thing:

```
Console.WriteLine(lst.ToString<int>());
```

output:

```
shekhar, shekhar, shekhar, shekhar
```

so this time i used `int` and it still ran because that T has no use other then changing the Method Prototype.

So simply why are you using `ToString` Literal as Method name, as it already exist and you **can't override it in a Extension method**, this is the reason you had to use that `T` to make it generic. Use some different name like

```
public static string ToMyString(this IList<String> list)
```

That way you wouldn't have to use generic as it useless there and you could simply call it as always.

---

That said your code is working for me. here is what i tried (**in LINQPAD**):

```
void Main()
{

    List<string> lst = new List<string>();
    lst.Add("shekhar");
    lst.Add("shekhar");
    lst.Add("shekhar");
    lst.Add("shekhar");
    lst.ToString<string>().Dump();
}

    public static class ListHelper
    {
        public static string ToString<T>(this IList<String> list)
        {
            return string.Join(", ", list.ToArray());
        }

        public static string ToString<T>(this String[] array)
        {
            return string.Join(", ", array);
        }
    }
```

And the output was `shekhar, shekhar, shekhar, shekhar`

Since you have specified that `T` in `ToString<T>` you will need to mention a Type like `string` or `int` while calling the ToString method.

Comment: However when I call  files.ToString<string>() it does work :) its longer than files, but i still like it :)

Comment: As i said in start i ran this Code in LINQPAD there we have Dump() method to see whats inside an object.. in normal C# program just call `Console.WriteLine(lst.ToString<string>());`

Comment: You could pass anything as T and it will work. Your not using the generic type in the method. files.ToString<string>(), files.ToString<int>(), var str = list.ToString<Dictionary<int, string>>(), etc.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you want to replace what `files.ToString()` returns. You will not be able to do that without writing a custom class to assign `files` as (i.e. inherit from List and override `ToString()`.)

First, get rid of the generic type (`<T>`), you're not using it. Next, you will need to rename the extension method because calling `files.ToString()`will just call the List's ToString method.

This does what you're looking for.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<string> { {"a"}, {"b"}, {"c"} };
        string str = list.ToStringExtended();
    }
}


public static class ListHelper
{
    public static string ToStringExtended(this IList<String> list)
    {
        return string.Join(", ", list.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override ToString for a specific class with a partial class.

For example, this was generated by Entity Framework scaffolding:

```
Namespace Models
    Public Class TPower
        Public Property Start As Date
        Public Property Finish As Date
        Public Property WattHours As Integer
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Adding this in a separate source file:

```
Namespace Models
    Partial Public Class TPower
        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return $"{Start}-{Finish} {WattHours}"
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Gives this:

[image]

(Paste code into [the Telerik converter](https://converter.telerik.com/) for C# >;-)