# Can a C# extension method be added to an F# type?

Tags: c#, f#, extension-methods

I've got somebody's F# library with a type in it:

```ml
module HisModule

type hisType {
    a : float;
    b : float;
    c : float;
}
```

I'm using it in C#, and I would like to add a "ToString()" method to it, in order to facilitate debugging.

But the following doesn't seem to work:

```cs
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string ToString(this HisModule.hisType h)
    {
        return String.Format("a={0},b={1},c={2}", h.a, h.b, h.c);
    }
}
....
var h = new hisType();
Console.WriteLine(h.ToString());  // prints "HisModule+hisType"
```

Any ideas why not?

Comment: Note that every object in .NET already has a ToString() member method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create extension method for toString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982479/how-to-create-extension-method-for-tostring)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your question is "yes".  Your sample does not succeed, however, because method resolution succeeds when it finds `object.ToString()`, so the compiler never looks for extension methods.  Try it with a different name:

```
public static class MyExtensions 
{ 
    public static string Foo(this HisModule.hisType h) 
    { 
        return String.Format("a={0},b={1},c={2}", h.a, h.b, h.c); 
    } 
} 

....   
var h = new hisType();   
Console.WriteLine(h.Foo());
```

Answer (score 11):

As others have pointed out, the ToString on object will always be a better match than your extension method. You should probably change the signature of your extension method; changing the name is probably the right way to go.

Moreover: you said that the purpose of this thing was to facilitate debugging. Overriding ToString might be the wrong thing to do there; ToString might be used for something other than debugging. I would be inclined to make my own specially-named method whose name clearly reflects the purpose of the method.

If you are creating a new type and want to have special display behaviour in the debugger, the easiest thing to do is to use the [Debugger Display Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992.aspx).

If you want to get really fancy to display a complex data structure in an interesting way, consider writing a [Debugger Visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I think you can not do that, as `ToString()` is always there, in any object of CLR world. 
Check out [Eric Lippert answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982479/how-to-create-extension-method-for-tostring).

Comment: I've been adding ToString() extension methods on enum types in the past so I don't think this is definitely the problem, resolution should fall back on Object.ToString() last.

Comment: @DavidGrenier: Overload resolution *always* prioritizes an applicable candidate method on a base type over an extension method. Can you demonstrate a situation where C# does not do so? If so, you've found a bug and I'd like to know about it. Thanks!

Comment: I tried repeating the experiment in LINQPad and it didn't work. I might just be crazy here. This was done at a previous workplace and the evidences are clearly against.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper type (with an implicit conversion) that overrides `ToString`.

```
class MyType {
    private readonly hisType _hisType;
    private MyType(hisType hisType) {
        _hisType = hisType;
    }
    public static implicit operator MyType(hisType hisType) {
        return new MyType(hisType);
    }
    public override string ToString() {
        return String.Format("a={0},b={1},c={2}", _hisType.a, _hisType.b, _hisType.c);
    }
}

hisType y;
MyType x = y;
```